# Remove element from JComboBox once selected in another

Tags: java, jcombobox

I've looked around on the internet but had no luck. How would I go about solving this:

I have 4 JComboBoxes with identical data, and each time an element is selected, I want that element to be temporarily removed from all other JComboBoxes (until it's unselected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have identical data, how about creating 4 temporary arrays and once you choose the selected index you may remove this index from other arrays.

Maybe this is not the best practice but will do the job until you have better solution.